# pushing is undefine in jquery

Tags: jquery

```
var saved_recipe = [];
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch",
  data: "apiKey=" + apiKey + "&query=" + query 
  async: 'true',
  success: GetReci
});

function GetReci(response) {
  console.log(response)
  var r = "";
  var i = 0;
  var GetRecipe_Arr = response.results;
  $.each(GetRecipe_Arr, function(index, value) {
    var title = GetRecipe_Arr[i].title;

    i = i + 1;
  })

  console.log(saved_recipe);
  $(document).on("tap", "#saved_recipe", function(e) {
    saved_recipe.push(GetRecipe_Arr[i]);
    console.log(saved_recipe)
  });


  $('#recipeoutput').html(reci);
}
```

I was trying to push the particular recipe that is 'like this' to a new array called saved_recipe. But the value i push become undefine, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `GetRecipe_Arr`'s length is 3,

In the following line

```
console.log(saved_recipe);
$(document).on("tap","#saved_recipe",function(e){
  saved_recipe.push(GetRecipe_Arr[i]);
  console.log(saved_recipe)
});
```

the index `i` refers to 3, but `GetRecipe_Arr[3]` will be `undefined`.

You are trying to access `i` after the loop is over.